# Error while storing jXDatePicker1 Date value in database

Tags: java, sql, derby, swingx

I am using swingxLabs' component jXDatePicker1 to pick date in a graphical format and trying to store it in the database made in derby. My code was this:

```
Date date=jXDatePicker1.getDate();

 PreparedStatement statement = connect
      .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BILLING (DATE, DHRNUMBER) VALUES('"+date+"', "+dhrNumber+")");
```

The error which i am getting is:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.
```

Am i doing it right? Or there can be some other way to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine 1- JDBC is expecting a java.sql.Date or 2- you're trying to insert/update the String value of the Date object rather then using the actual Date object itself. If you use a PreparedStatement, you can use the setDate method. Show us your update code

Comment: can you send me any link to how to use setDate method?

Comment: Look at PreparedStatement in the JavaDocs and look up the JDBC trail from Oracl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This alternative totally worked for me:

```
    Date d=jXDatePicker1.getDate();
    System.out.println(d);
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String date=df.format(d);
    System.out.println(date);

PreparedStatement statement = connect
      .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BILLING (DATE) VALUES('"+date+"')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Derby's built-in DATE datatype supports a short list of string formats: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqlj18730.html

Since you are using PreparedStatement, the best thing to do is to prepare the statement

```
INSERT INTO BILLING (DATE, DHRNUMBER) VALUES(?,?)
```

and then substitute your actual values using the setDate() and setInt() methods from:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html